# Удаление повторяющихся слов из строки

Tags: javascript

Есть строка, необходимо удалить из неё всё повторяющиеся слова т.е из строки http://spb.site.ru/der/der/ удалить der/
Строка формируется автоматически.

```
var stroka = "http://spb.site.ru/der/der/";

function removeWords( str ) {
    var lastWord = '';
    return str.replace( /([^\s]+)(\s|$)/g, function( all, w, e ){
        return lastWord.toLowerCase() == w.toLowerCase() ? '' : ( lastWord = w ) + e;
    });
}
console.log( removeWords( stroka ) );
```

Подскажите, где неправ, почему работает не верно?

Comment: Ну, для начала, `\s` это пробельные символы, слеш это не пробельный символ

Comment: `/([^\/]+)(\/|$)/g`  попробуйте с такой регуляркой

Comment: спасибо большое

Answer (score 5):

```
"http://spb.site.ru/der/der/"
  .match(/(http:\/\/|https:\/\/|[-\.A-Za-z0-9]+\/)/g)
  .filter((v, i, a) => a.indexOf(v) === i)
  .join("")
```

Вернет `http://spb.site.ru/der/`
Идея в том, что мы бьем ссылку на массив из составляющих, дальше фильтруем повторы через `filter` и обратно клеим в строку.

Правда подход довольно специфичен. Будет работать ТОЛЬКО для ссылок и обязателен слэш на конце. Набросал на скору руку, главное идею показал. Можем улучшить :)

Comment: вместо filter с indexOf лучше `new Set` использовать, он сам удалит повторяющиеся строки

Comment: @Grundy Да, в целом удобно. Я видимо не застал уже `Set` в `js`. На другом языке фронт теперь пишу.

Answer (score 2):

В качестве альтернативы, можно воспользоваться возможностью регулярных выражений использовать значения уже захваченных групп. Это позволит найти повторяющиеся части.

В простых случаях может помочь следующее регулярное выражение

```
/\/(.+?)\/(.*)\1\/?/
```

Пример использования:

```js
function log(str) {
  console.log('source', str);
  console.log('replaced', str.replace(/\/(.+?)\/(.*)\1\/?/, '/$1/$2'));
}

log("http://spb.site.ru/der/der/");
log("http://spb.site.ru/wander/der/");
log("http://spb.site.ru/derwan/der/");
log("http://spb.site.ru/der/sdf/der/");
```